# How do I get wkhtmltopdf to produce PDFs with selectable and searchable text?

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

I've installed wkhtmltopdf on Mac OS X via homebrew and I've also tried compiling it (along with the patched version of Qt) by hand. In both cases, the PDFs it generates do not contain any selectable, copyable, or searchable text. Instead each page seems to be its own monolithic image.

However, the [binary version](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/downloads/detail?name=wkhtmltopdf-0.9.9-OS-X.i368&can=2&q=) for Mac OS that's provided on the website *does* produce selectable text. But it's an older version (0.9.9) and does not support some of the newer features in 0.11 rc1 that I need.

How do I get newer versions to produce PDFs with selectable and searchable text?

Comment: I am using .11 on a ubuntu box and selectable text works.

Comment: There's a new static binary that might work for you http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/downloads/detail?name=wkhtmltopdf.dmg&can=2&q=

Answer (score 7):

Currently there is [a bug in the queue](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/issues/detail?id=886) of that project for just this case.

Unfortunatly, the recent binary for Mac OSX (0.11-rc1) still has this problem

You can get a older (but newner than the original poster's version) version (0.10) that does work [here](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/downloads/detail?name=wkhtmltopdf-0.11.0_rc1-static-i386.tar.bz2&can=2&q=).

Answer (score 1):

[Ensure the body element has a defined, non-zero height.](http://pivotallabs.com/users/jpalermo/blog/articles/1985-standup-01-13-2012-will-the-real-13th-please-stand-up)

Comment: That didn't solve the issue for me. Do you perhaps have additional details or even an example test case?